# how to run 2 matlab script in same time in third script named main.m

Tags: matlab

I have 2 script multiObjectTracking.m and tracking.m I want that the 2 script run at the same time by executing him in third script main.m the two script doesn't communicate with each other :
I run this code but they execute sequentially :

```
 run('multiObjectTracking1.m');
 run('multiObjectTracking.m');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to open two instances of Matlab and run one script from each instance.

Comment: The other way would be to create functions out of them and use `parfeval`

Comment: Don't do it! Running macros in parallel is a terrible idea. If you are going to run things in parallel (for example with parfeval), at least write it as functions. This minimize the risk of unintentionally shared data.